Uniqueness of representation for orthonormal basis in Hilbert Spaces
I'm studying Hilbert spaces for Functional Analysis and we've recently got to the definition of an orthonormal basis for the space H (infinite dimensional) consisting of $\{e_n\}_{n \in N} \in H$ such that $|e_n| = 1$, $(e_n, e_m) = 0$ (inner product) for $m \neq n$, and the linear subspace generated by finite linear combinations of the $e_n$'s is dense in H. We showed that for any element $u \in H$ we can write it as $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}(u, e_k) e_k$. My question is, is this way of representing u in terms of the basis unique? If there are scalars ${a_n}_{n \in N}$ such that $u = \Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}(u, e_k) e_k$, is $(u, e_n) = a_n$ for every n? I think that they should be, but I don't know how to prove it. Any help is appreciated!!

Hint: if $u = \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k e_k$, what is $(u, e_k)$?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It suffices to show that the vector $0$ can be written uniquely. Suppose $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ are scalars such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n e_n = 0$, that is, $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n e_n = 0$. Let us show that $a_k = 0$ for each $k \in \mathbb N$. To this end, take any $k \in \mathbb N$ and consider the following:
\begin{align*}
0&=\left\langle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n e_n, e_k \right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n e_n  , e_k\right\rangle \\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \left\langle \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n e_n  , e_k\right\rangle  = a_k.
\end{align*}
